# Making calls sequentially with RXJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I need to display data that are coming from my database when the user launches the app (they are available immediately), and then, I need to replace them by data that are coming from the network as soon as they are available.

I tried this by doing that :

```
mDisposable = mRepository.getHighlights(forceReload)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<PaginatedData<List<Article>>>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(PaginatedData<List<Article>> articles) {
                mView.updateData(articles.getData(), articles.isFirstPage(), articles.isLastPage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }
        });
```

And the getHighlights() method :

```
return Observable.concat(getHighlightsFromDataBase(), getHighlightsFromNetwork()).map(new Function<List<ArticleResponse>, PaginatedData<List<ArticleResponse>>>() {
            @Override
            public PaginatedData<List<ArticleResponse>> apply(@NonNull List<ArticleResponse> articleResponses) throws Exception {
                // ...
            }
        });
```

The issue is that it only calls "apply()" (in the "map" method) when getHighlightsFromDataBase() AND getHighlightsFromNetwork() are done.

So instead of having this order :

```
getHighlightsFromDataBase()
getHighlightsFromNetwork()
map()
onNext()
map()
onNext()
```

I need to have :

```
getHighlightsFromDataBase()
map()
onNext()
getHighlightsFromNetwork()
map()
onNext()
```

The "onNext" that I'm talking about is **the onNext of the method that calls getHighlights();** (so that I can update the view each time I've got new data).

What can I do to achieve that ?

Thanks !

Comment: So why don't you simply apply map for each observable separately?

Comment: I'd say your code looks fine and should do exactly what you expect it to do: Load from DB first, then from the network. However, `concat` will subscribe to `getHighlightsFromNetwork()` as soon as `getHighlightsFromDatabase` has emitted `onCompleted`. If I am not mistaken, this may be before or after the last/only item from `getHighlightsFromDatabase` has passed through the `map`. You may want to try to add some artificial delays to see the behavior more clearly.

Comment: Oh, and just in case you were being more literal in your "expected order" part than I thought at first: *Of course* `getHighlightsFromNetwork()` will be called right in the beginning - since it is used as an argument for `concat`, it needs to be evaluated before you even get to the `map` - Java still has strict (as opposed to lazy) evaluation, after all. However, `getHighlightsFromNetwork` must return an `Observable` and the *subscription to that Observable* will be lazy - as I said above it will happen after the `onCompleted` of `getHighlightsFromDataBase`.

Comment: I updated my question, can you please take a look at it ? Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, still looks fine, except I expect your app to crash as you don't have a `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` in there. Please try both `Observable.concat(getHighlightsFromDataBase(), getHighlightsFromNetwork().delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))` and `Observable.concat(getHighlightsFromDataBase(), getHighlightsFromNetwork().delaySubscription(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))` and see how the behavior changes.

Comment: I tried this with this simple test : http://pastebin.com/5ntnL4S9

And it gives me this output :

getDataFromDb
getDataFromNetwork
Value : 1
Value : 2
Value : 3
Second map
onNext
Value : 4
Value : 5
Value : 6
Second map
onNext
onComplete

I think that the issue is that it calls getDataFromDb THEN getDataFromNetwork, THEN the map methods. I need it to call getDataFromDb(), then map then onNext, (to return the value to my view), then getDataFromNetwork, etc.

Comment: Are you making sure that `getHighlightsFromNetwork` is on the io scheduler?

Comment: I think you are reading too much, or the wrong things, into your logs: Yes, `getDataFromNetwork` is logged immediately. But no, this is not a problem. You see, you are logging before you are even creating the (faux) network `Observable`. The relevant thing to log would be `Observable.fromArray(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6))).doOnSubscribe(/*NOW we are starting the network request!*/)`. The subscription is when you are about to start the actual work - NOT the point at which are creating the `Observable`.

Comment: Oh my god ! You're right ! When logging in doOnSubscribe, I have this output : 

getDataFromDb
Value : 1
Value : 2
Value : 3
Second map
onNext
getDataFromNetwork
Value : 4
Value : 5
Value : 6
Second map
onNext
onComplete

Thanks a LOT for the precious information you gave me !

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked out in the end!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    getHighlightsFromDataBase().map().doOnNext() {      
      getHighlightsFromNetwork().map().onNext()
    }
```